# IAP is working with TestFlight build. Is it will work Live app Also?

Tags: iphone, swift, in-app-purchase, testflight, mkstorekit

I Have implemented IAP in my swift project. It is working fine. it will work with live app or not.

Secondly url of Live app and BetaTester url is same or not?

Comment: can you please tell me which URL on you are confused?

Comment: I am confused with Live url

Comment: i can't understand properly which live URL?

Comment: kLiveServer = @"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt" This one boss

Comment: you have to add live url  for live application. for more details or another way to receipt verification visit https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YES**. if your testflight app working then your Live App is also worked fine. 
in BetaTester App testing is show you `Environment Sandbox` when you are Purchasing in IAP. when your App is Live then the Environment is autometically changed to live.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly yes. Except that in TestFlight IAPs will work when they are not approved. Where as they will not work in the live app until they are approved. So make sure to submit your IAP for approval before the app goes live.